# What is the maximum length for an ENUM value?

Tags: mysql, enums, types

Searched the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html), but to no avail.
What is the maximum length for an enumeration value, i.e. the string literal?

Comment: Use normalization (a separate table and a foreign key relationship), and you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The limit isn't on the length of the literal string, but rather on the table definition.

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html) states that

> Each table has an .frm file that contains the table definition. The server uses the following expression to check some of the table information stored in the file against upper limit of 64KB.

which is then followed by an ad-hoc equation expressing the approximate size of a table definition.

For a simple test, in a table with a couple fields already, I got my enum up to 63136 characters long, and the .frm was 71775 bytes big (slightly larger than 70KB), so the limit is approximate.  At that point, MySQL complained `#1117 - Too many columns`, which is misleading to say the least.

Interestingly/oddly/worthwhile to note, the character set of the enum will change the maximum length. -- even if you're using normal characters which should only require 1 byte each.

Answer (score 6):

An ENUM column can have a maximum of 65,535 distinct elements. (The practical limit is less than 3000.) A table can have no more than 255 unique element list definitions among its ENUM and SET columns considered as a group.